# Since starting 10 years ago

Tags: american-english

My question is: why "starting" and not "started" I'm not a native speaker.

A. J. Hoge wrote:

"Since starting 10 years ago, Eve has felt bad."

I would write like this:
Since started 10 years ago, Eve has felt bad.

Comment: I would write “Eve has been feeling bad for the last 10 years.”. Unless that’s not what was meant.  Perhaps the meaning is that since she started [her job] 10 years ago she has been feeling bad.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: #Jim it is OK, but I ask about the sentence from A. J. Hoge.

Comment: #Laurel I just edited my question.

Comment: Why would you think that "started" is correct and "starting" isn't?

Answer (score 3):

**A.J. Hoge was correct in his writing.** Here's why:
*Starting* is a gerund. According to Dictionary.com, a gerund is

```
a form regularly derived from a verb 
and functioning as a noun
```

That definition may be confusing to you (and that's OK!), so I'll simplify it for you.
A gerund is a verb (an action, e.g. to run; to fly) acting as a noun (an object or idea, e.g. an egg; a key; freedom). This change in form (from verb to noun) is accomplished by adding *ing* to the end of the verb. See, it's really easy! Here are a few examples:

```
- run > running
- fly > flying
- read > reading
- start > starting
```

So, in the sentence,

```
Since starting 10 years ago, 
Eve has felt bad.
```

*Starting* is a noun/gerund. `Since starting` is a prepositional phrase, and, according to the definition of a prepositional phrase, a ***noun*** or a ***gerund*** must be present. 
*Started* is a *past-tense **verb***. Therefore, it cannot be used in the prep. phrase, unless you convert it into the gerund, ***starting***.

The only way that you could use your sentence is by adding a *noun* into the phrase, such as *she*, thus becoming this:

```
Ever since she started 10 years ago,
Eve has felt bad.
```

Let me know if you have any questions! ;)